# Is it possible in php-fpm to override terminate_timeout per script?

Tags: php

I'm using php-fpm and have set a terminate_timeout=3 to stop any running scripts taking longer than 3 seconds, which works great.

However, occasionally, I will have a php script that NEEDS to run a bit longer, for instance, it's accessing a 3rd party billing API that takes some time to return.

Is there any way that script can override the default timeout of php-fpm and ask for a little longer amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options declared in `php-fpm.conf` are not reachable from `ini_set()` (along with the options defined for the fpm *pool*). However,

- create another pool

create two pools with different options (note the two different ports)
(usually in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/`)

```
[pool1]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
request_terminate_timeout = 0
...

[pool2]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
request_terminate_timeout = 10s
...
```

- You could also use the [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function (from the core, it doesn't work in PHP safe-mode)
  (I'm guessing (didn't try) the php-fpm request_terminate_timeout option should probably be removed in this case if its value < set_time_limit)

Comment: set_time_limit occasionally didn't work if something was blocking for a long time or sleeping or whatever. The Pools idea is exactly what I ended up doing, and then in nginx I simply to a location filter for the url I want to send to the other pool and point to the correct ip:port